# Facebook Post link to wall error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post a link on the facebook wall. but i got these error. please help me anyone to solve this error.

```
  $config = array(
   'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
   'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',

  );  


  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
   $facebook = new Facebook($config);
   $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
 if($user_id) {

  try {
   $facebook->api('/$user_id/feed','POST',
               array(  'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken(),
                 'message' => 'Hello World!',
                 'link' => 'www.example.com'
                    )
            );
} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
$result = $e->getResult();
 error_log(json_encode($result));


    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                   'scope' => 'publish_stream'
                   )); 
    echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
    error_log($e->getType());
    error_log($e->getMessage());
  }   

  echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';
} else {

  as the redirect_uri, so we don't
  // need to specify it here.
  $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'publish_stream' ) );
  echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

}
```

`{"error":{"message":"(#1) An error occured while creating the share","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}`

OAuthException

`(#1) An error occured while creating the share
 {"error":{"message":"(#1) An error occured while creating the share","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}`

OAuthException
 (#1) An error occured while creating the share

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to add `'type' => 'link'` and see if it works? As far as I've read on Facebook forums this is actually a bug.

Answer (score 1):

you are not doing anything wrong, there is a small php mistake in your code due to which your $user_id variable is not being read. 
solution,replace single quote with double quote around `/$user_id/feed` in your code. try this it will work:

```
$facebook->api("/$user_id/feed",'POST',
               array(  'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken(),
                 'message' => 'Hello World!',
                 'link' => 'www.example.com'
                    )
            );
```

Comment: i have also try this  ** "/$user_id/feed and /me/feed**  but not work

Comment: that's weird, I had copied your complete code and after changing api key and secret and fixing that quote bug.. i was able to post. check the [post](http://www.facebook.com/smitatest/posts/416142551787014) . anyway also check if your api key and secret both are correct.

Comment: both are correct .Any other setting during the creating in apps (api key and secret)